# Golang defer is not always executed

Tags: go, server, tcp, memory-leaks, goroutine

I'm running a Golang TCP server that receives a connection, spawns a goroutine to handle that connection, then spawns a new goroutine to read from the connection and write data to a channel. There's also a simple function to read data from the channel.

The idea is that if the client closes the connection, the **ReadFromConn** goroutine will receive an error on reading and then return. The defer code would write to the **done** channel and close both the **done** and **queue** channels. The consumer code would stop processing if the **done** channel has data and return whatever result it was at that moment.

The other case is that the consumer can decide that it has enough data to make a decision and return. This would lead the execution back to the **Handle** function. When that function returns, the defer on the **Handle** function would close the connection, causing the **ReadFromConn** goroutine to receive an error on reading from the connection and close all the pending channels.

This works great, but I'm doing some load testing, and noticed that the memory usage of the Golang server after the test is done is not decreasing like all the other parts of the application do when the load stops. I took some of the IDs and checked the logs. I see that **sometimes** (not all the time) the **ERROR READING FROM CONN** message is shown, but there is no **READ_FROM_CONN DEFER** log, so I think the defer is never being called. As a result, the **ProcessQueue** hangs reading from the channel because it is never closed, and the **CLOSING...** log from the **Handle** function is missing too.

At least, that's what I think is happening, and I believe it's the reason why the memory consumption never drops when the load test ends because the code is still running some goroutines reading from channels that should be closed by the defer code on **ReadFromConn**. This behavior is not predictable; it doesn't happen with all connections, so I don't know what could be wrong.

Here is a simplified version of my Golang server:

```
package main

import (
  "os"
  "net"
  "fmt"
  "io"
)

type CustomStruct struct {
  Type string
  Stop bool
}

func main() {
  // Creates server
  server, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:80")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("failed to bind listener to socket", err)
  }
  defer server.Close()
  fmt.Println("Listening new connections V2")

  // Starts reading from the server
  for {
    conn, err := server.Accept()
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("failed to accept new connection:", err)
      continue
    }

    go Handle(conn)
  }
}

func Handle(conn net.Conn) {
  defer conn.Close()

  id := "some uuid for each conn"

  // Creates channels
  queue := make(chan []byte, 512)
  done := make(chan bool)

  // Starts reading from the server
  go ReadFromConn(id, conn, queue, done)

  result := ProcessQueue(id, queue, done)

  fmt.Println(id, "CLOSING...")

  // Do stuffs with result...
  fmt.Println(id, result)
}

func ReadFromConn(
  id string,
  conn io.Reader,
  queue chan []byte,
  done chan bool,
) {
  defer func() {
    done <- true
    close(queue)
    close(done)
    fmt.Println(id, "READ_FROM_CONN DEFER")
  }()

  tmp := make([]byte, 256)
  for {
    _, err := conn.Read(tmp)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(id, "ERROR READING FROM CONN " + err.Error())
      return
    }
    if (tmp[0] == 0x00) {
      return
    }
    queue <- tmp
  }
}

func ProcessQueue(
  id string,
  queue chan []byte,
  done chan bool,
) CustomStruct {
  defer fmt.Println(id, "GET_TRANSCRIPTION_RESULT ENDED")
  fmt.Println(id, "GET_TRANSCRIPTION_RESULT STARTED")

  result := CustomStruct{
    Type: "transcription",
    Stop: false,
  }

  for {
    select {
    case <-done:
      fmt.Println(id, "DONE DETECTED")
      return result
    default:
      fmt.Println(id, "DEFAULT")
      payload, open := <-queue
      if open == false {
        fmt.Println(id, "QUEUE IS CLOSED")
        return result
      } else {
        fmt.Println(id, "QUEUE IS OPEN")
      }
      // ... Do stuffs with payload, if certain condition is met, of the result of processing payload, return
      if (payload[0] == 0x01) {
        return result
      }
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a complete example, but your [code doesn't compile on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/9kEv4m81r7G). When I fix the issue, I get a deadlock.

Comment: @erik258 I updated the code to remove external packages, but still cant run on the playground, i think it may be due a limitation of the playground to run a never ending tcp server? If i run the updated code in a docker container it runs fine

Comment: Looking at the code, when you have one goroutine in `ProcessQueue` in the `<-queue` statement, there's nothing that could try to read from the `done` channel. Consequently the `done <- true` send statement you have in the `ReadFromConn` defer statement cannot proceed, and the `close(queue)` is unreachable. Consider not trying to send to `done` but just closing it to signal that.

Comment: @fizzie I think i dont get it, there should always be messages on queue, otherwise the channel queue should be closed, so the <-queue should never hang, the idea of using done channel is because if the client closes the connection i dont want ProcessQueue to keep reading remaining messages, i want to process the current and check for done and return, the messages that wasnt able to process before connection is closed should be ignored

Comment: What I mean is: when `ReadFromConn` exits and the `defer` block runs, it's clearly no longer writing any more messages to `queue`. Yet the `ProcessQueue` goroutine is likely still waiting in the `payload, open := <-queue` statement, since that's where it spends most of its time. The `defer` block can't reach the `close(queue)` and `close(done)` statements, because before either of those it tries to do `done <- true`. You have a deadlock situation if one goroutine is blocked at `done <- true` and the other in `<-queue`. Try removing `done <- true`; the `close(done)` serves the same purpose.

Comment: In this particular case, you don't need a done channel at all. Just close the queue. The reader becomes simpler `for { data, open <- queue; if !open {return} }`

Comment: @fizzie You're absolutely right; that was the problem. Writing to a channel is a locking operation; I didn't knew that and thought locking was only for reading. I changed the code to only close the channel and not write to it because it would have the same effect. I'm new on Stack Overflow, so I don't know how to give you credit for your answer. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what the issue is, but controlling the lifespan of the reader could be achieved a lot more cleanly using a context object. The context avoids having to manage the channel objects as closely, and provides a clean way to report errors from the goroutine if needed using `context.Cause(ctx)`.

Example setup could look like this:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancelCause(context.Background())
queue := make(chan []byte, 512)
go ReadFromConn(id, conn, queue, ctx, cancel)
result := ProcessQueue(id, queue, ctx, cancel)
```

The defer call could be to place an error in the context cause, which causes the `ctx.Done` method to now return a channel with a value present. This method is also repeatable, meaning multiple goroutines can all receive a value instead of just one when using the simple channel approach.

When sending to the queue, you can select on `ctx.Done` as well to prevent waiting forever on a queue that is no longer being read from. Similarly, you can do that for reading from the queue as well.

```
func ReadFromConn(...) {
  defer cancel(fmt.Errorf("reader defer"))
  ...
  for {
    ...
    select {
    case queue <- tmp:
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return
    }
  }
}
```

```
func ProcessQueue(...) {
  defer cancel(fmt.Errorf("queue defer"))
  ...
  for {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
      ...
    case payload := <-queue:
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: When using a "done" type channel, usually the best practice is to never write to it, just close it.  And that's [how Go's context.Context works internally](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.6:src/context/context.go;l=453;drc=61f5a672edd6cce959a47e20dcfb59eaaa5ebd56).

Also important in this response is how the select is written. When written like this (where each case is a channel read), the select processes whichever is processed first.

The original example only processes the `done` channel if it is populated _after reading the queue_, which is why it deadlocks.